# showing difference in overhead in transactions

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have an assignment where I can't figure out the last part: question is as follows:

> Demonstrate also that the isolation level READ COMMITTED has a larger
>   overhead than READ UNCOMMITTED. Document your results using time
>   measurements.

Tried using `nanotime()`, and I get the result, UNCOMMITTED is slower than COMMITTED. But where do I go from here to show that a the latter has a larger overhead?

example part of code:

```
    PreparedStatement updateStatement = null;
    PreparedStatement updateTotalStatement = null;
    PreparedStatement selectStatement = null;

    String update = "UPDATE test.test3 SET price = ? WHERE randomString = ?";
    String updateTotal = "UPDATE test.test3 SET total = total + ? WHERE randomString = ?";
    String select = "SELECT * FROM test.test3 WHERE price > 5";

connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);

        updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement(update);
        updateTotalStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateTotal);
        selectStatement = connection2.prepareStatement(select);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            updateStatement.setInt(1, i);
            updateStatement.setString(2, "testString");
            updateStatement.executeUpdate();
            updateTotalStatement.setInt(1, i);
            updateTotalStatement.setString(2, "testString");
            updateTotalStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        updateStatement.close();
        updateTotalStatement.close();
        updateResult2 = selectStatement.executeQuery();
        selectStatement.close();
        connection.commit();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
```

Comment: What numbers to you see? Did you "warm up" the systems adequately? Never benchmark the first execution of anything. This includes the first iteration of your loop, because the JDBC driver may defer prepared statement processing until first execute call.

Comment: I believe the overhead you need to demonstrate is in the *reading* performed by other "users" while an uncommitted update is pending. Maybe you should (re)read the part of your learning material that talks about the UNCOMMITTED overhead, so you know what it is you're supposed to demonstrate.

Comment: what do you mean by warm-up?
is it like, run a couple of thousands of select statements before benchmarking?

Comment: Google [`performance test warm up`](https://www.google.com/search?q=performance+test+warm+up)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, clarified quite a lot.